# Error: macro names must be identifiers using #ifdef 0

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have the source code of an application written in C++ and I just want to comment something using:

```
#ifdef 0
...
#endif
```

And I get this error

> error: macro names must be identifiers

Why is this happening?

Comment: I think you misremembered; #ifdef 0 is an error in C as well as C++.

Comment: You are right I misrembered, It does not work in C, I am not going to delete the question because maybe someone in the future makes the same mistake.

Comment: @Eduardo Thanks for not deleting the question.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The #ifdef directive is used to check *if a preprocessor symbol is defined.* The standard (`C11 6.4.2 Identifiers`) mandates that identifiers must not start with a digit:

```
identifier:
    identifier-nondigit
    identifier identifier-nondigit
    identifier digit
identifier-nondigit:
    nondigit
    universal-character-name
    other implementation-defined characters>
nondigit: one of
    _ a b c d e f g h i j k l m
    n o p q r s t u v w x y z
    A B C D E F G H I J K L M
    N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
digit: one of
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

The correct form for using the pre-processor to block out code is:

```
#if 0
: : :
#endif
```

You can also use:

```
#ifdef NO_CHANCE_THAT_THIS_SYMBOL_WILL_EVER_EXIST
: : :
#endif
```

but you need to be confident that the symbols will *not* be inadvertently set by code other than your own. In other words, don't use something like `NOTUSED` or `DONOTCOMPILE` which others may also use. To be safe, the `#if` option should be preferred.

Comment: I have some code that I compile occasionally that is compiled with -DNEVER_USED.  I haven't investigated why - I hate to guess.

Comment: @Pax: actually, it is very unlikely that the C compiler allows the notation - it would be erroneous if it did.  See also my comment to the question.  I suggest removing your sentence "It's likely that...".

Comment: Not all C compilers are ANSI-compliant. I've used plenty of embedded compilers that allow all sorts of trickiness like that. But I'll fix it.

Answer (score 14):

Use the following to evaluate an expression (constant 0 evaluates to false).

```
#if 0
 ...
#endif
```

Answer (score 7):

This error can also occur if you are not following the marco rules

Like

```
#define 1K 1024 // Macro rules must be identifiers error occurs
```

Reason: Macro Should begin with a letter, not a number

Change to

```
#define ONE_KILOBYTE 1024 // This resolves
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#ifdef 0
...
#endif
```

#ifdef expect a macro rather than expression
when using constant or expression

```
#if 0
...
#endif
```

or

```
#if !defined(PP_CHECK) || defined(PP_CHECK_OTHER)
..
#endif
```

if #ifdef is used the it reports this error

```
#ifdef !defined(PP_CHECK) || defined(PP_CHECK_OTHER)
..
#endif
```

Where #ifdef expect a macro rather than macro expresssion

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can also hit this error if you accidentally type:

```
#define <stdio.h>
```

...instead of...

```
#include <stdio.>
```