# Xcode Project Macro Name Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, build, linker

My project runs directly on the device when I build to it. However, when I try to Archive it to use it with TestFlight, I get the following error:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
Macro names must be identifiers
```

Why is that happening The only macro I have defined is this in AppDelegate:

```
#define TESTING 1
    #ifdef TESTING
    [TestFlight setDeviceIdentifier:[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]];
    #endif
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#define TESTING 1
#if TESTING
    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n\ttesting !!!!!\n\n\n\n\n");
#endif
```

You may also want to look at this post: [Error: macro names must be identifiers using #ifdef 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426736/error-macro-names-must-be-identifiers-using-ifdef-0)

Comment: I did try that. I commented the whole thing out and I still get the same issue - I've never defined a macro before though.

Comment: If I get that error even after commenting it out then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Try to do Product->Clean before archiving.

Comment: I tried. I get it as a warning when I build on the simulator. When I archive, its an error and not a warning. How can I find which macro its talking about? How do I debug this?